# Wrap a Start() method and Completed event in a Task

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I am migrating an application from Silverlight to Windows 8 and I wanted to take advantage of the System.Theading.Tasks API.  I have a number of classes that have a Start() method and fire off a Completed event when they are done.  Would anyone know how to wrap this in a Task?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional async pattern was a Begin and End method for each async call. You can wrap that in a Task with the FromAsync method.

[Here you can find some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx). You could use the same function but then with your Start and End methods.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of framework elements don't support that model.  For example, the WPF Animation element just returns void from Start().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) class. It'll allow you to manually control the completion of your task.

For example:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
myService.Completed += (sender,args) => { tcs.SetResult(args.Value) };
myService.Start();

return tcs.Task;
```

Comment: Doesn't this leak the task?